# Referencing fonts with Apache FOP

Tags: java, apache, fonts, apache-fop

We want to use Arial Unicode MS in our pdf documents, but because of commercial restrictions, we are not able to embed it. We are trying to reference the font using the referenced-fonts feature in FOP, but without success. This is our `fopConfig.xml`:

```
<fop version="1.0">
<renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
        <filterList>
            <value>flate</value>
        </filterList>
        <fonts>
            <referenced-fonts>
                <match font-family="Arial Unicode MS"/>
            </referenced-fonts>
        </fonts>
    </renderer>
</renderers>
```

Anybody knows how to make this work? I have been working on it for hours already and couldn't find a solution.

Thank you!